# How should I encode a form value I send with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: asp-classic

I wonder what the right way is to encode a form value when it is send to an .asp page with a `XMLHttpRequest` and then decode it on the .asp page before I insert it to my db. So I can use characters like this `#%?´:;!+-'`

Do I use `encodeURIComponent(the string value here)`

So lets say the form is in page1.asp

```
<form action="#"  id="saveuploads" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" class="form-ajax-submit">
<input type="text" name="artikel" >
</form>

// lets say I have a string in the form with the value `#%?´:;!+-'`

artikel=encodeURIComponent('#%?´:;!+-'')
fdu.append("artikel", artikel);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "upload2.asp");
xhr.send(fdu);
```

And then in page2.asp
Should I decode it with

artikel=decodeURIComponent(request.form("artikel"))

And then insert artikel to db...

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the Javascript in your question client side or server side?

Comment: Hi John. Its client side.